# Can I dispute too many transactions? (credit card)

Tags: credit-card, dispute

There's a restaurant here that's a hit or miss. Sometimes they mess up my order. Sometimes food sucks. But sometimes they're great and when they're great its really good. Maybe I'm a little addicted on their food.

They don't care about reviews people leave.

I once left this note while creating my order "Cancel my order if you're gonna mess it up otherwise I'll dispute the transaction". It didn't make a difference. I disputed that transaction choosing this option "I didn't receive what I ordered".

I disputed a few more times. Didn't leave a note again because they don't care.

I'd like to order more from here so I'm wondering.. Can I dispute too many times? I don't want my bank to close my credit card account. Every client of a bank has a lifetime value and if am unprofitable to them, they'd close my account, right?

Comment: My personal experience is that disputing frequently harms the merchant more than it harms you. You might want to send your credit card company a letter explaining the situation just so you have something in writing. They might suggest not using that merchant, for example. If enough other people are chargebacking, the merchant will most likely lose their ability to accept credit cards

Comment: Part of me wants to think there's a difference, from the credit card company's post of view, between "I didn't get what I ordered" and "I repeatedly don't get what I order yet choose to continue ordering anyway".

Comment: Also, too many disputes and the merchant will probably just block you as a customer.

Comment: I should add that my personal experience was chargebacking *different* merchants (not the same one repeatedly) and these were all online "card not present" transactions. The only time I chargebacked the same merchant repeatedly was after I cancelled a service and they kept billing me monthly

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can dispute too many transactions.

> Credit card disputes cost merchants and banks. So if your credit card
> company determines that you’re filing too many chargebacks, you may
> find yourself on its blacklist too.

Further, you are supposed to pursue remedies with the restaurant in each individual case, before resorting to the dispute mechanism:

> Only after the company refuses to address your concerns should you
> initiate a chargeback.

https://www.elliott.org/answers/credit-card-disputes-how-to-use-them-the-right-way/